# dynamically changing the width of the column in jtable with Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

Developing an application in netbeans and java swing
 I want to change the width of my columns in a jtable 
 to adjust to  the length of data in the cell
 aftr a google search i stumble upon Binklye's blog 
 on the following link

http://binkley.blogspot.com/2006/01/getting-jtable-columns-widths-to-fit.html

below are code snippets

```
{

    final TableCellRenderer renderer = getTableHeader()
            .getDefaultRenderer();

    for (int i = 0; i < getColumnCount(); ++i)
        getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(
                renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(this,
                        getModel().getColumnName(i), false, false, 0, i)
                        .getPreferredSize().width);
}

public Component prepareRenderer(final TableCellRenderer renderer,
        final int row, final int column) {
    final Component prepareRenderer = super
            .prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    final TableColumn tableColumn = getColumnModel().getColumn(column);

    tableColumn.setPreferredWidth(max(
            prepareRenderer.getPreferredSize().width,
            tableColumn.getPreferredWidth()));

    return prepareRenderer;
}
```

will love to have someone help with the implementation of the codes.

On the other hand if there is another soution , will be glad to have a look at it.

Comment: I'd be concerned with overriding the tables prepareRenderer in this way (but that's me). Instead, I'd use the concept, but apply it in such away that you'd have to call when the data actually changes

Comment: don't change the state of the component during the paint cycle! State includes model and prepareRenderer is part of paint cylce. Instead, update the size when something has happened that might affect it, f.i. after data changes in a tableModelListener.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/).

Comment: I can not find library for this. TablecolumnAdjuster

Comment: @Krishna, did you click on the link?

Comment: @Krishna, `i read that whole block.` did you read the `Get the Code` heading and click on the link?ter?

Comment: which one link if there is Table Column Adjuster. then there should be library for that is it???

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
jtable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

You can write your own custom method which will be fired when you add row or delete it.
Sample code:

```
public static void resizeRow(JTable table) {
        TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < columnModel.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(i);
            column.setPreferredWidth(/*your logic of setting width*/);
        }

    }
```

Comment: There are multiple option. You can set the way you want ;)

Comment: I am using the jtable in a jscrollpane so I had to disable the auto- resize property in netbeans

Comment: @SchinPasaikar wll check and get back